# reCAPTCHAの制限回数超過による挙動について

Tags: recaptcha

「reCAPTCHA v2」の「非表示 reCAPTCHA バッジ」を使用させていただいております。

reCAPTCHAには無料版だと月100万回までとされているようなのですが、それを超えると具体的にどのような挙動をするのでしょうか。

■やりたいこと
・formの送信にreCAPTCHAのチェックを行う
・reCAPTCHAの制限回数を超過していてロボットの判定が行えない場合は素通しする
　※ロボットによるform送信を許容する

■気になっている点
・reCAPTCHAの制限回数を超過してformの送信自体ができなくなる仕様だと困る

■ソース（参考）

```
<html>
<head>
<title>reCAPTCHAテスト</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="submitType" name="submitType" value="">
<button
id="recaptchaButton"
class="g-recaptcha"
data-sitekey="サイトキー"
data-callback="successCallback"
data-error-callback="errorCallback"
type="submit"
>送信</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function successCallback(response) {
$('#submitType').val('successCallback');
$('#form1').submit();
}

function errorCallback(response) {
$('#submitType').val('errorCallback');
$('#form1').submit();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google の FAQ も参照してください。直ちに停止されるとの記載は見当たりませんが、ウィジェット部分にメッセージが表示されるのと、管理者宛にメール通知が届くようです。

[Frequently Asked Questions | reCAPTCHA | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#are-there-any-qps-or-daily-limits-on-my-use-of-recaptcha)

> ##### Are there any QPS or daily limits on my use of reCAPTCHA?
>
> (中略)
>
> If a v2 site key exceeds its monthly quota, then the following or a similar message may be displayed to users in the reCAPTCHA widget for the remainder of the month: `This site is exceeding reCAPTCHA quota.` Before quota is enforced, site owners will be notified by email three times and given at least 90 days to migrate to reCAPTCHA Enterprise. Site keys are considered over quota if more than 1000000 calls per month are used for any domain. This includes if this volume is spread across multiple keys on the same domain.